# Getting device's Bluetooth MAC address

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, bluetooth

I need to self identify a device using its bluetooth MAC address or UUID. It seems there is no way to get a device's MAC or UUID in Xamarin, Android or iOS. Is there any way to do this? I've tried using the following statement:

```
    macAddress = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
```

but this is not working and reruns null, I checked the code behind Secure and there is actually no bluetooth_address. I used the same code and I easily got back bluetooth_on which is in Secure code so I'm sure the code is working but there is not any bluetooth_address.

Any idea how I can do this? If I can't get this my entire design has to change.

Best

Comment: Certainly on iOS there is no way to get a unique device identifier, such as a MAC address. This is by design for privacy reasons. You can get `identifierForVendor` which is unique for your apps on a given device but can change if the device is reset or your apps are removed and reinstalled

Comment: The Android approach you have in your question only worked in versions 6 and 7(?) and that security/privacy hole was patched to return null in 8+ (unless it is a system/OEM signed app).